# add iquote params to bazel custom toolchain

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm currently writing a custom bazel toolchain to support all of the compiler and linker flags that I want, however I'm running into problems specifying the `-iquote` param.

Currently my repo structure looks roughly like this:

```
/
    src/
        BUILD
    test/
        BUILD
    toolchains/
        BUILD
    WORKSPACE
```

I would like to specify that bazel add `-iquote src` to all compilation lines, however if I add it as a flag inside of a feature, bazel adds single quotes around the parameter, which seems to confuse gcc (i.e. `'-iquote src'` rather than `-iquote src`).

How can I add this to my custom toolchain? https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html lists `quote_include_paths` as a "build variable" however I don't know how to use or set it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with = instead of space to separate arg name and value? Like `'-iquote=src'`

Comment: `'-iquote=src` didn't work, but you gave me the idea and `-iquotesrc` _did_ work.